# How to get elements of a modal dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am building a Chrome extension and I want to use Javascript to grab specific elements in a popup module.

Basically, I have a calendar like so:
[Calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gI5n.png)

And I can refer to anything on this page using "document.querySelector()".

However, when I click on the appointment, it brings up a popup like so:
[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUKzM.png)

and when I use "document.querySelector()" on any element within the popup, it returns null.

How can I dynamically update the DOM? So that when the appointment is clicked on and the popup appears, my "document.querySelector()" can grab input box values from this popup?

Comment: Mutation Observers. Go read the MDN documentation and there is an async function called ```waitForElm``` ... it will resolve the element you are looking for and then you can do w/e you want with it once it is available.

Comment: Did you actually access the popup's document? You need to declare your content script with all_frames and possible match_about_blank to do so.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. I figured out that it was because the popup was an "iframe" and so I had to use the waitForElm that was suggested on the iframe itself and not any elements within the iframe. Then once the iframe was on the page, I could declare it as my new document and query it like you would any other document.